# Unable to receive message sent to acivemq by C# in Java

Tags: java, c#, activemq-classic

What I want to do is to send messages via Apache Activemq between C# app and Java app.

C#:

```
using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
            {
                IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "queue://ISI");

                // Create a consumer and producer
                using (IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination))
                {
                    // Start the connection so that messages will be processed.
                    connection.Start();

                    ITextMessage request = session.CreateTextMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));

                    /*request.NMSCorrelationID = "abc";
                    request.Properties["NMSXGroupID"] = "cheese";
                    request.Properties["myHeader"] = "Cheddar";*/

                    producer.Send(request);

                    return request;
                }
            }
```

Java:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(isiProperties.getMqUrl());
                connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                connection.start();

                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                Destination destination = session.createQueue("ISI");

                MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
Message message = consumer.receive();
                    if(message instanceof TextMessage) {
                        try {
                            String text = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            StatusChangeMessage obj = mapper.readValue(text, StatusChangeMessage.class);
                            if (obj instanceof StatusChangeMessage) {
                                StatusChangeMessage received = (StatusChangeMessage) obj;
                                Order order = orderRepository.findOne(received.getOrderId());
                                order.setStatus(received.getStatus());
                                orderRepository.saveAndFlush(order);
                            }
                        } catch(JMSException e) {

                        } catch(IOException e) {

                        }
                    }
```

The C# app correctly sends messages (it is visible in activemq admin interface) but there are no active subscribers (Java app should do that). Do you see anything wrong here?

Basically, breakpoint on `if(message instanceof TextMessage) {` does not get executed.

Comment: If you are using a debugger, then what is the type of `message` ? You can see it in your debugger and see why it's not an instance of `TextMessage` ...

Comment: Debugger never reaches `if(message instanceof TextMessage)`. It hangs on `Message message = consumer.receive();`

Comment: Did you validate that your client's are connecting to the same broker instance?

Comment: Yes, when I kill activemq, then Java app gets messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solutioin. It was two-steps problem. Firstly, Windows firewall influenced activemq. Secondly, client library probably didn't fully match to the server. Problem finally gone after downgrading server to 5.8.0.